# Renaming files in sub folders

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
for /r /d  /s %%d in (*.*) do (    
    if exist "%%d\(1).txt" ( 
        rename "%%d\(1).txt" "%%d(-123).txt"
    )
)
```

When I test this, nothing happens. What am I missing from this?

I've edited this several different ways, I can't get it to work.

With the `/s`, without it, with the `if exist`, and without, with `(*.txt)`, nothing, I don't really need the `if exist`, but just testing it.

What I am aiming for is this: `Main Folder\folder\Sub Folders`

Inside sub folder I can have 80 to 150 txt files named like this `(1).txt`, `(2).txt` etc. and I'm trying to get this batch file to find all `(1).txt`, in every sub folder, and rename it to `(-123.txt)`, and find all `(2).txt` and rename them to `(-121).txt`, all the way to `xx.txt` number files.

Since I have no easier way to rename these files, I would have to repeat this script many times within the same batch file.

Once this scripts works, I will have to make many copies and make a very long script batch. I know their is now script that will rename the way I need, but if it can scan all folders, and subfolders, from the main folder that would be so much better

```
(1).txt => (-123).txt
(2).txt => (-121).txt
(3).txt => (-119).txt
(4).txt => (-87).txt
(5).txt => (-55).txt
(6).txt => (-110).txt
(7).txt => (-101).txt
```

Right now I have this, but I am going folder by folder.

Rename.bat:

```
(1).txt => (-123).txt
(2).txt => (-121).txt
(3).txt => (-119).txt
(4).txt => (-87).txt
(5).txt => (-55).txt
(6).txt => (-110).txt
(7).txt => (-101).txt
```

Is there a way to make my current bat files read sub folders, since I already have the `rename.bat` files. I have a simple basic `ren "(1).txt "(-123).txt",` this works well, but moving this to over 100 to 200 folders 1 by 1 is taking to long

I have lets call it main.txt folder 
and inside the main folder I have the rename.bat 
and inside the main folder I have a work folder 
and inside the work folder I have 100 folders with 100 subfolders 
I'm trying to make my rename.bat read the work folder from the main folder 
and scan every folder, and subfolder, and find every matching txt file 
when it scans, finds, and matches every txt file it would rename them

```
(1).txt => (-123).txt
(2).txt => (-121).txt
(3).txt => (-119).txt
(4).txt => (-87).txt
(5).txt => (-55).txt
(6).txt => (-110).txt
(7).txt => (-101).txt
```

Right now I copy each folder 1 by 1 and place them in the main.txt folder 
and double click rename .bat, and that is taking forever

and I also copy the rename.bat file to the folders where the files are and double click it there

I have more then 100 folders so this is taking for ever

Comment: Hello. 123-2=121-2=119-2=117? where did (87) come from? Please explain so we can help.

Comment: @Toni the numerical numbers get renamed to - unnumerical order and is not complete so it will not count from 123 to 1, this is how it looks 1 =-123, and 10 = -45, and 50 = -78, as you can see I rename them like that,  the minus is important and the number is important to my order, and how I match them to the numerical numbers, so I know using standard counting tools will not work, what it needs to do is fined all folders with (1).txt, and rename them all to (-123).txt and so on

Comment: If I understand your task correctly, leave `Rename.bat` untouched and in the same location as your other batch file, which should also be the root directory of the tree you're trying to iterate. Then your batch file could read: `@For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B /S /A:D') Do @PushD "%%G" && (Call "%~dp0Rename.bat" >NUL 2>&1 & PopD)`.

Comment: @Compo Thank you, but I have many sub-folders, this will call the rename.bat, but I would have to place a rename.bat in many folders, my goal here is to read as many folders and sub folders from main folder, using 1 renamer.bat

Comment: I will fix my questions, my original question was edited

Comment: No you would not, I've already told you where to place `Rename.bat`! In the root of your target tree, along side the other batch file! So if all of the files were in directories and subdirectories under `C:\Users\Javier\Desktop`, you'd have `Rename.bat` and this new batch file in `C:\Users\Javier\Desktop`, then just doubleclick on your new batch file! I would advise you to try the advice I have given before telling me I am wrong!

Comment: @Compo - oh when I saw the `call` to me it appeared that it was calling it from those subfolders, ok I got it now, and sorry I meant no disrespect, I simply wanted to know if I had to place the rename.bat in every folder, I thought it was scanning for the rename.bat to run them

Comment: Please leave a comment once you have tested it, to provide feedback.

Comment: @Compo - Thank you very much, this one setup is going to fix other stuff for me as well, it did work very well

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /a "numfiles=20"

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s "C:\path\to\your\folder"') do (
    set "pt=%%~dpa"
    set "pt=!pt:~0,-1!"

    set "opts=tokens=* delims="
    for /l %%i in (1,1,!numfiles!) do (
        if exist "!pt!\(%%i).txt" (
            call:getrenamestring "!opts!" renamestring
            move /y "!pt!\(%%i).txt" "!pt!(!renamestring!).txt"
        )
        set "opts=tokens=* skip=%%i delims="
    )
)
goto:end



:getrenamestring
set "optstmp=%~1"
for /f "usebackq %optstmp%" %%s in ("file where you store the renaming patterns IN ROW ORDER.txt") do (
    set "%2=%%s"
    exit /b 0
)
exit /b 0


:end
endlocal
exit /b 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your task correctly, leave `Rename.bat` untouched and in the same location as the batch file, I have posted below, which should also be the root directory of the tree you're trying to iterate. So if all of the files were in directories and subdirectories under `C:\Users\Javier\Desktop`, you'd have `Rename.bat` and this new batch file in `C:\Users\Javier\Desktop`, then just doubleclick on your new batch file!

```batch-file
@For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B /S /A:D') Do @PushD "%%G" && (Call "%~dp0Rename.bat" >NUL 2>&1 & PopD)
```

Comment: This worked great for anyone using this just change the Rename.bat to your own bat name, Thank you very much

Comment: Hey I have 1 question, last night when I kept messing with my original script question, some how I was able to rename all the (1).txt files to foldername(-123).txt, it some how grabbed the name of the folder, would you have an idea how I did that, when I was going to test your answer I saw that my (1).txt were all renamed, now I am trying to figure that out, because on one of my projects needs something like that. just a question, if you tell me that with this script something like that is not possible, then I will see what I did, but I know I was messing with the script I question on